# php count array multidimensional with loop by value

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, count

Hello Thanks for the help, this my code.

I have an **number.txt** file like this :

```
5041655 5492272 1109
5041657 5492274 1109
5041656 5492273 1109
5041060 5491807 1102
5041656 5492273 1102
5036664 5486420 1101
```

And I load **number.txt** in php file like this :

```
<?

$file = fopen("number.txt","r");
while(($get = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE){

    $data = preg_split("/[\t]/", $get[0]);
    $username = $data[2];

    print_r($username);
}

?>
```

But i dont know how to print as follows :

```
number : 1109 is number1
number : 1109 is number2
number : 1109 is number3
number : 1102 is number1
number : 1102 is number2
number : 1101 is number1
```

Thank You.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Please show some effort.

Comment: Need to detail description for you doubt or questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
<?php
$array = array(
     1109,
     1109,
     1109,
     1102,
     1102,
     1101
);

for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++)
{
    echo "number : ".$array[$i]." is number".$i + 1 ."<br />";
}
?>
```

**Update 1**

Answer updated as your question.

```
<?php

$file = fopen("number.txt","r");

$i = 1;
while(($get = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
{
    //$data = preg_split("/[\t]/", $get[0]);
    $data = explode(" ", $get[0]);

    $username = $data[2];

    //print_r($username);
    echo "number : $username is number".$i++."<br />";
}

?>
```

OUTPUT

[image: The output after Update 1]

**UPDATE 2**

```
<?php

$file = fopen("number.txt","r");

//$i = 1;
$numbers = array();
while(($get = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
{
    //$data = preg_split("/[\t]/", $get[0]);
    $data = explode(" ", $get[0]);

    $numbers[] = $data[2];
    //$username = $data[2];

    //print_r($username);
    //echo "number : $username ";//$i++."<br />";
}

$numbers = array_count_values($numbers);
foreach($numbers as $key => $val)
{
    echo "number : $key found $val times<br />";
}

?>
```

Output of update 2

[image: Output of update 2]

**FINAL ANSWER**

```
<?php

$file = fopen("number.txt","r");

$numbers = array();
while(($get = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
{
    //$data = explode(" ", $get[0]);
    $data = preg_split("/[\t]/", $get[0]);

    $numbers[] = $data[2];
    $number = array_count_values($numbers);
    echo "number : $data[2] number ".$number[$data[2]]."<br />";
}

?>
```

**FINAL OUTPUT**

[image: FINAL OUTPUT]

Answer (score 0):

For your understanding

```
 <?php
     $i = 1;
     foreach($array as $arr) {
       echo "<p>number : $arr[0] is number $i</p>";
       $i++;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading between the lines - I think this is what you are after.
This solution 'counts' the number of values that are the same, and increments the value if they are the same, or sets the counter back to 1.

```
$array = array(
     Array ( 0 => 1109 ),
     Array ( 0 => 1109 ),
     Array ( 0 => 1109 ),
     Array ( 0 => 1102 ),
     Array ( 0 => 1102 ),
     Array ( 0 => 1101 )
);

$i = 1;

foreach($array as $a){

    foreach($a as $k => $v){

        $i = ($prevValue == $v) ? $i+1 : 1;

        echo "<br>number : $v is number $i";

        $prevValue = $v;

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Chris,

Thanks for the help, your code is working. But i cant implementation in my code like above. Can you help me 

Thank You

Comment: You have changed the details in your question since I answered.  Originally, you showed the array.. ..now you are showing a .txt file.  What does your data source/array look like?